# wordpress, blank lines at start of page

Tags: php, wordpress, session

I have develop a site using wordpress. Its running fine on local machine (windows xp) and on testing server (ubuntu). But on live server its giving errors which is given bellow. There are 2 blank lines before this and and after these errors as well. On testing server I notice two blank lines in start, however its running fine.

I tried and remove some blank line in header.php, index.php and some other files but got no luck.

The live site URL is http://mbsocial.bsslsites.com

```
  <br />
    <b>Warning</b>:  session_start() [<a href='function.session-start'>function.session-start</a>]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /home/bsslsite/public_html/mbsocial/wp-includes/functions.php:4954) in <b>/home/bsslsite/public_html/mbsocial/wp-content/plugins/wp-e-commerce/wpsc-core/wpsc-constants.php</b> on line <b>16</b><br />
    <br />
    <b>Warning</b>:  session_start() [<a href='function.session-start'>function.session-start</a>]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/bsslsite/public_html/mbsocial/wp-includes/functions.php:4954) in <b>/home/bsslsite/public_html/mbsocial/wp-content/plugins/wp-e-commerce/wpsc-core/wpsc-constants.php</b> on line <b>16</b><br />


    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
        <head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the error messages, I'm going to guess there's some whitespace before `<?php` in wpsc-constants.php

Comment: No black space is there in wpsc-constants.php before <?php

Comment: Are you absolutely sure? No newlines or spaces or anything? Do you echo anything anywhere? What is on line 16 of that file?

Comment: Yes no spaces or anything. here is the code from that file 
 `<?php
// Left Overs
$wpsc_currency_data = array();
$wpsc_title_data    = array();

/**
 * wpsc_core_load_session()
 *
 * Load up the WPEC session
 */
function wpsc_core_load_session() {
 if ( !isset( $_SESSION ) )
  $_SESSION = null;
    //error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_WARNING);
 if ( ( !is_array( $_SESSION ) ) xor ( !isset( $_SESSION['nzshpcrt_cart'] ) ) xor ( !$_SESSION ) )
  session_start();
}

/**
 * wpsc_core_constants()
 *
 * The core WPEC constants necessary to start loading
 */`

Comment: Can you pastebin that or edit your original post to retain formatting please?

Comment: Also, what is at line 4954 of functions.php?

Comment: there was blank line at the end of functions.php. I have remove and home page is fixed now. Thanks for your hint.

Comment: Close enough :P - remember to look at the files and lines in the error messages next time.

Answer (score 0):

You obviously need to fix the errors. Luckily, they point you right to the soruce of your problem - Line 16 of wpsc-constants.php.

It also seems you should have your local dev and testing environments configured properly to show your these errors, and have your production environment configured properly to NOT show these errors.

Answer (score 0):

The most common scenario for this to appear is when you have a blank character or a blank line echo-ed to the browser before setting header information (cookies in this case). My suggestion is to try and go through your theme's functions.php file and wp-e-commerce/wpsc-core/wpsc-constants.php files and make sure they start with `<?php` - no blank spaces or newlines before that.